# ListBox filled by DataTemplate doesn't scroll WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, listbox, scroll

I fill listbox via this code:

```
<ListBox Height="188" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="277,0,0,0" Name="listBoxAtributeValue" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="191" MaxHeight="188" MaxWidth="191">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackPanel.Background>
                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFA029" Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </StackPanel.Background>
                            <Label Content="{Binding lblText}" />
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding txtBoxContent}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ListBox>
```

but I can't scroll it.
Here is an image of listBox: [Here](http://i48.tinypic.com/fuyja1.jpg)

How can I fix that? Thak you.

Comment: Why you put an ItemsControl in a ListBox? ListBox is an ItemsControl with selection abilities.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. It works now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `ItemsControl` inside your `ListBox`. A `ListBox` is already an `ItemsControl`.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. It works now. Thank you very much!